# How can I find critical field in tsmc65 transistor parameter?

Tags: transistors, modeling, cadence, electric-field, virtuoso

How can I find critical field in tsmc65 transistor parameters? Critical field is the field which electron velocity in transistor go into the saturation region.

Comment: that will depend on how you construct your transistor using the TSMC65 process. I don't have access to any PDK for that process, but I bet there's quite a few different types of logic gates and transistors in the standard libraries you'll find.

Comment: Also, there's not one, but several 65nm processes by TSMC. Do you mean CRN65LP with deep n-well? Or CRN65GP?

Comment: Hello guys. @MarcusMüller, I am just using "nch" component. No special name.

Comment: Don't know what that is, sorry!